# extracting from dataset using another dataset in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have the following dataset FULLDS

```
 id  date         value
 A  "05/31/2000"   10
 B  "06/31/2000"    11
```

I have another dataset NewDS which is

```
id  startdate enddate
A   "04/30/2000"  "05/31/2002"
etc
```

I would like to only keep data in the FULLDS that is matched according to its in NewDS and is only between the start and end dates

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `proc sql`.  The following pulls the data using a select:

```
proc sql;
    select f.*
    from FULLDS f join
         NewDS n
         on f.id = n.id and f.date between n.startdate and n.enddate;
```

You can actually delete the non-matching rows by doing:

```
proc sql;
    delete from f
        where not exists (select 1
                          from NewDs n
                          where f.id = n.id and f.date between n.startdate and n.enddate
                         ) ;
```

Comment: Note, this would only work if those are actually dates, and not just strings that store date-like values.  You'd need to add some `input` statements if not.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat faster way to do this (as well as a SASsy way) is to use formats.

Take NewDS, make a new dataset based on that called `fmts` or some such, and rename the variables to `start` and `end`, create a variable `label` with a value of `'VALID'`, and rename `ID` to `fmtname`.

Then `proc format cntlin=fmts; quit;` (fmts = name of your dataset made above).

Then you use `putn` like so:

```
data want;
set fullds;
if putn(date,id) = 'VALID';
run;
```

This assumes all date variables (in both datasets) are truly date values, and not character variables.  If they are, then `start`, `end`, and the value going into the putn will all need to be `input` to dates.